# How to prevent my button's onclick for  5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like:

```
<button id="button" onclick="alert('Hi')">a button</button>
```

I want to *deactivate* the button onclick action, let's say for 5 seconds after the page loads.
Note: I don't want to make the button disabled, just want it's onclick action not to work untill 5 seconds.

Comment: Telling us why will help us figure out the best solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply just remove the `onclick` attribute, and then put it back 5 seconds later.

```
var onClickFunc = $('#button').prop('onclick');
$('#button').removeProp('onclick');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#button').click(onClickFunc);
}, 5000);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KX5g7/1/

Comment: I don't know how we lived without `.prop()` before 1.6.

Comment: @iambriansreed: With `.attr` :-P

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery to bind the event after a timeout of 5 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert('Hi');
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @kil I figured as much. See Rocket's answer.

Comment: I did an improvement on my asnwer, to unbind it after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').attr('savedclick', $('#button').attr('onclick')).removeAttr('onclick');  
    setTimeout(enableButton, 5000);    
});

function enableButton(){
    $('#button').attr('onclick', $('#button').attr('savedclick')).removeAttr('savedclick');
}
```

​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yupt9/1/)

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.  Pass functions.

Comment: @Rocket There's nothing dangerous about using `eval` (explicitly or implicitly) if you've hard-coded the string you're passing to it. It's just slightly less efficient.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Less efficient, and bad practice.  There's no reason to use it.  It's like using a screwdriver as an awl.  You can, but shouldn't. :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
        $('#button').unbind('click');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#button').bind('click');
        }, 5000);
    });​
```

---

**EDIT:**

This seems to not unbind the event as **Rocket** told, so, I think that a good solution could be to remove the attribute that fire the event:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').attr('onclick', '');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#button').attr('onclick', 'alert("Hi")');
    }, 5000);
});​
```

Comment: Other way around, he wants it unbound when the page loads, and re-bound 5 seconds later.

Comment: Done, now is disabled for 5 seconds and then start to bind the event onClick.

Comment: `$('#button').unbind('click');` doesn't seem to unbind the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, don't put the `onclick` inline.

In your `$(document).ready(...)` function, use `setTimeout` to wait 5 seconds with a callback function to set the onclick (`$('#button').click(function(btn) { alert('Hi'); });`)

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that from the question. In that case [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10452652/866022) is the way to go